# Stream files from HDFS using Apache Spark Steaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, spark-streaming

**How can I stream files already present in HDFS using apache spark?**

I have a very specific use case where I have millions of customer data and I want to process them at a customer level using apache stream. Currently what I am trying to do is I am taking entire customer dataset and **repartition** it on **customerId** and creating 100 such partitions and ensuring unique customer multiple records to be passed in a single stream.

Now I have all the data present in HDFS location

> hdfs:///tmp/dataset

Now using the above HDFS location I want to stream the files which will read the parquet file get the dataset. I have tried the following things but no luck.

```
// start stream
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamApp")

// Create the context
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(60))
val dstream = ssc.sparkContext.textFile("hdfs:///tmp/dataset")

println("dstream: " + dstream)
println("dstream count: " + dstream.count())
println("dstream context: " + dstream.context)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()


NOTE: This solution doesn't stream data it just reads data from HDFS
```

and

```
// start stream
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamApp")

// Create the context
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(60))
val dstream = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs:///tmp/dataset")

println("dstream: " + dstream)
println("dstream count: " + dstream.count())
println("dstream context: " + dstream.context)

dstream.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am always getting 0 result. Is is possible to stream files from HDFS if is already present in HDFS where no new files are publishing.

Comment: The easiest approach is to move the files into `hdfs:///tmp/dataset` after streaming context is started.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** This functionality is not supported in spark as of now. The closest you can get is by moving the files into `hdfs:///tmp/dataset` after starting the streaming context.

---

`textFileStream` internally uses `FileInputDStream` which has an option `newFilesOnly`. But this does not process all existing files but only the files which were modified within one minute (set by config value `spark.streaming.fileStream.minRememberDuration`) before streaming context. As [described in jira issue](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6061?focusedCommentId=14348160&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14348160)

> when you set the newFilesOnly to false, it means this FileInputDStream would not only handle coming files, but also include files which came in the past 1 minute (not all the old files). The length of time defined in FileInputDStream.MIN_REMEMBER_DURATION.

Or

You could create an (normal) RDD out the existing files before you start the streaming context. Which can be used along with the stream RDD later.